# Push notification stopped working when downloaded from App Store

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

When i test Push Notification with apn_development_cer, it works with the loaded app on  the iPhone device from Xcode.

But, when i am downloading the same application from App Store or with the Ad Hoc Distribution on the same iPhone device from Xcode, it just stops sending Push Notification with apn_production_cer.

Thanks in advance!

Vivek Dandage

Answer (score -1):

Are you using sandbox (development) environment which is available through gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195 ? For app store build, you will need production environment which is available through gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195;

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jignesh! Yes, i am using sandbox environment where is works. However, for production environment, we are using gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195 but notification still doesn't work.